# MsSQL 2008: How to remove SHUTDOWN rights from sa user

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have an application that runs in SQL Server 2008 and I was needing to disable the shutdown permissions

Comment: Permissions are not checked for sysadmin role members so one cannot revoke any permissions from those members, including the sa login.

Comment: Isnt possible to disable shutdown function?

Comment: No, but a bad actor who's a sysadmin role member can do a lot more damage than just shutting down the instance.

Comment: The problem atm i have an application sa login, but it is packed and i cant change the sa login. And i have problems with SQL Injection, the only query that they run is shutdown because it is a small query the application only accept 12 chars.

Comment: You can't remove roles from the `sa` user, but you can login with another sysadmin-level account (Windows or SQL Login) rename it to something like `oldsa` and then create a new SQL Login called `sa` with lesser privileges and map it to the required databases and database users. Try it on a non-production server first.

Comment: You could buy some time until a proper fix is in place, by creating a process(es) which is suspended/executing WAITFOR. shutdown will wait for the suspended process and any subsequent shutdown calls will fail (because there is already a shutdown waiting). Implementation wise, overlapping sql agent jobs could execute the waitfor.Caveat: shutdown will become a runaway process even if the client connection is closed.